# Prolog: Decrementing variable in argument

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I am new to Prolog and was tasked with a Fibonnaci predicate fib( N, F) where N is the number in sequence, and F is the value.  What I came up with does not work, but the solution I found seems identical to me... I cannot understand the difference.

My version:

```
/* MY VERSION, DOES NOT WORK */
fib( 0, 0).
fib( 1, 1).
fib(N,F) :-
    N > 1,
    fib(N-1,F1),
    fib(N-2,F2),
    plus(F1,F2,F).
```

The working version:

```
/* FOUND SOLUTION, DOES WORK */
fib( 0, 0).
fib( 1, 1).
fib(N,F) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    N2 is N-2,
    fib(N1,F1),
    fib(N2,F2),
    plus(F1,F2,F).
```

Obviously the problem has something to do with me using "N-1" and "N-2" as arguments rather than assigning those values to new variables first.  But I don't get it... because in other recursive Prolog codes, I have successfully done just that (decremented a variable right in the argument slot).  Does this make sense?

Thanks!

---

Below is an example where the "N-1" did work.

```
line( N, _, _) :-
    N =:= 0.

line( N, M, Char) :-
    N > 0,
    N mod M =\= 1,
    write( Char), write( ' '),
    line( N-1, M, Char).

line( N, M, Char) :-
    N > 0,
    N mod M =:= 1,
    write( Char), write( '\n'),
    line( N-1, M, Char).

square( N, Char) :-
    N > 0,
    line( N*N, N, Char).
```

A new version of fib/2 which also works!

```
/* NEW VERSION, CHANGED TRIVIAL CASES TO EVALUATE N */
fib( N, 0) :-
    N =:= 0.

fib( N, 1).
    N =:= 1.

fib(N,F) :-
    N > 1,
    fib(N-1,F1),
    fib(N-2,F2),
    plus(F1,F2,F).
```

Comment: I'd be curious to see how you successfully decremented a variable right in the argument -- I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: I did not know this before, but apparently `>` is like `is` in that it evaluates arithmetic (I want to put a link here but SO is interpreting the parens -- will add to my answer). Very neat.

Comment: Cool stuff (thanks for the link), but not sure the "<" or ">" evaluation trick explains why my line/3 predicate succeeds with a "N-1" argument.  Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In prolog,

```
1 - 2
```

Doesn't actually do any arithmetic (I know, right?), it creates a structure:

```
-(1, 2)
```

And `is` is a predicate that evaluates that structure:

```
is(X, -(1, 2))
```

Will unify X with `-1`.

Also apparently [`<` and `>` (and those like it)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.25%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/arith.html%27%29%29) are like `is` in that they evaluate expressions.

So that means that the difference between your `fib` predicate and your `line` predicate is that

```
fib(0, 0).
```

is using unification, ie, testing whether the terms themselves are equal:

```
foo(0).

?- foo(1 - 1).
false
```

Whereas a test like `=:=` tests for numerical equality:

```
foo(X) :- X =:= 0.

?- foo(1 - 1).
yes
```

Comment: That makes sense, but why does the "N-1" work in my "square" predicate below? Gah, I can't seem to add code in this reply, so I have edited it into my OP.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.  So it is indeed related to the ">"... specifically the "N>0" and "N=:=0" lines in my 3 line predicates are what cause the N-1 to get evaluated.  Thanks for explaining... never would have figured that one out on my own.

Comment: Ok... waaaait a minute.  Now I'm getting confused again.  My version of the "fib" predicate has N >= 0 as its first line.  So shouldn't this cause the N-1 and N-2 to get evaluated just like in "line"???  And a sidenote, the N >= 0 was excessive... what is actually needed is N > 1.  Updating OP.
Aaaand edit... nevermind again.  I think it is the trivial cases (0,0) and (0,1) that are causing the problem... as you actually pointed out. :-)

Comment: @Johnson Yes, it will cause it to be evaluated. But it also uses `fib(0, 0).` which won't. You could use `fib(X, 0) :- X =:= 0.`

Comment: Ha!  I just came up with that same solution myself a few mins ago, check the OP edit. :-)  Thanks again, I definitely understand it now.  Marking yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write the predicate somthing like the following.

`fib/2` is the outer 'public' interface. `N` is the position in the sequence (zero-relative). `F` gets unified with the value of the Fibonacci sequence at that position.

`fibonacci/5` is the inner 'core' that does the work.

- The 1st argument is the counter
- The 2nd argument is the limit
- The 3rd/4th arguments are the sliding frame required to compute the next item in the sequence. It should be noted that there is not required for a Fibonacci sequence start start with { 1 , 1 }. Any two integers will do.
- The 5th argument gets unified with the desired result.

Each clause in the core works as follows:

- If N is 0, F is unified with '1'.
- If N is 1, F is unified with '1'.
- If the limit has been reached, we're done. Unify F with the sum of the preceding two elements in the sequence.
- If counter is less than the limit, compute the next element in the sequence and recurse, sliding the oldest value out from the sliding window.

Here's the code:

```
fib( N , F ) :-
  N >= 0 ,
  fibonnaci( 0 , N , 1 , 1 , F ).

fibonacci( 0     , 0     , F , _ , F ).
fibonacci( 1     , 1     , _ , F , F ).
fibonacci( Limit , Limit , X , Y , F ) :-
  F is X + Y
  .
fibonacci( Current , Limit , X , Y , F ) :-
  Current < Limit ,
  Next is Current + 1 ,
  Z is X + Y ,
  fibonacci( Next , Limit , Y , Z , F )
  .
```