# How to do Arithemetic?

Tags: prolog

```
:- dynamic somepig/1.

runtest :-
    assert(somepig(6)), % Edit : just to be more precise, somepig is dynamic
    somepig(X),
    writeln(X+3).
```

This code ends up printing "6+3". I'm guessing either X is taking a type that can't do arthmetic or when I am assigning "somepig" then "6" is automatically considered a string or otherwise.

Is there anyway I can explicitly specify X to be an integer or otherwise ? Something like this maybe ?

```
runtest :-
    somepig(X is int)
    writeln(X+3). % outputs 9
```

Comment: @skin there is no way in standard Prolog to declare a variable type. You can restrict the domain of a variable relationally using a predicate like `number/1` but in any case (as explained below) that isn't your problem here.

Answer (score 2):

For prolog to recognize something as an arithmetic computation, you have to explicitly declare it using `is`:

```
runtest :-
    somepig(X)
    Y is X + 3,
    writeln(Y). % outputs 9
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7196766/869576) for more details.

Comment: Is there any other syntax, that is going to create like double the variable names for no reason.

Comment: I don't think there is. In prolog there is no such thing as using the 'result' of a 'function call', you need to unify it with another variable. (Granted, it could be possible to create syntactic sugar around the implementation, but I don't think that would really benefit the language.) Also, if doubling the number of variables is really a problem, you probably should simplify the predicates you are using.

Comment: Lol seriously ? I have to do 4-5 SIMPLE addition/subtraction. That's going to bloat my code now because of how prolog handles arithmetic.

Comment: @Steven You're not "declaring" arithmetic. You're using `is/2` to relate an arithmetic expression to a value. It's unfortunate that this relation only works one way. (Many of us prefer clpfd/clpqr because it does not have this limitation.)

Comment: @skin Prolog is known for its verbosity and it is not especially well-suited to numeric code. It has other strengths, and luckily we have found we can rely on every other programming language for things like that. I agree with Steven though, you should not experience a "doubling" of variables unless you've seriously misunderstood something.